# Bootstrap vertical-align Button beside alert div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have here a bootstrap grid where an alert lays beside a button.
The problem is that the button won't align properly vertical to the alert:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-info text-center">
        some Text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buttontext</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/BaNntnSJHI

any idea how to fix that?

Comment: In witch position you want to put the button exactly

Comment: as it is already at the top of vertical-align, only possibilities would be middle and bottom, i assume if ever there's a solution it would be pretty the same, right?

Comment: The downvote is for what? After 2 years? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this, unfortunately, because [vertical alignment in CSS is a pain](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/). If you're willing to use a table to do this, then you can just use standard table vertical alignment to great effect; otherwise, your best bet would probably be to use CSS tables but that itself will bring you a whole lot of additional layout pain, especially if the alert can stretch to multiple lines whereas the button may not be as tall.

For your own sanity I'd suggest just putting the button inside of the alert instead of next to it. Easier to understand and assuming the button and the alert are functionally related, grouping them visually like that may work better to imply connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i accepted this as an answer, since there is no obvious "easy" way for doing it. I already placed the button inside the alert (as you also suggested), this is not what i actually wanted, but its not a big deal regarding the whole layout. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you get exactly what you were looking for; I'm pretty sure you could make this work using CSS tables and some additional markup, but this is one of those times where the solution doesn't seem worth the trouble as opposed to lightly reworking the design. Especially given the button's own layout trickiness. If the alert is guaranteed to be short you could maybe throw a top margin on it to push it down and fake it, but even that's a hack.

Comment: It's working with adding margin-top to the button, but that's just a very bad workaround, since i can't predict the alert's height :D I'm fine now with putting the button IN the alert and not beside. Thanks again!